# Web Form Not Inheriting Master Page on Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, webforms, master-pages

Alright. I am making a school project using Visual Web Developer, and I need to use a Master Page. When I make a new web form based on my master page, it inherits the colors of the master page, but there is a table which is not inherited. Here is my master page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Master1.master.vb" Inherits="Master1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server" background-color: #00FF00;>
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style2 {
                height: 57px;
                width: 2363px;
            }
            .auto-style3 {
                height: 57px;
                width: 48px;
            }
            .auto-style4 {
                height: 48px;
            }
            .newStyle1 {
                background-color: #FF00FF;
            }
            .auto-style5 {
                width: 369px;
                height: 214px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: blue;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="newStyle1">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                <table class="newStyle1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Items>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Default.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="About.aspx" Text="About" Value="About"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </Items>
                            </asp:Menu>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style3">
                            <img alt="CS Logo" class="auto-style5" src="cSk.png" /></td>
                        <td class="auto-style2">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Master Page VB Code:

```
Partial Class Master1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
End Class



 Web Form Attempted to Inherit Master Page:

%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master1.master" %>

<script runat="server">

</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

[image: Master Page]

Comment: Try putting the script inside `ContentPlaceHolderID="head"` ?

Comment: Thank you. Solved my own problem by moving the table outside the div.

Answer (score 1):

You should only place HTML elements inside placeholders in a master page if you wish to overwrite this content in subsequent child pages.

The problem with your child page is that it overwrites the placeholder containing the table with empty HTML.

`<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>`

If you wish to inherit content, do not place shared content in placeholders.

If you must adopt this practice of placing shared content in placeholders, do not overwrite this content in the child page. So in your example:

<s>`<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>`</s>

Would display the table in the master page.

Hope that helps.